# How to get property value from JavaScript object when key is 0_1

Tags: javascript

```
var temp = '{"name":"abc","0_1":"padforn"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(temp).name);
console.log(JSON.parse(temp).0_1);
```

The `temp` variable has two keys.
Please how to get the value use key '0_1'?

Comment: Some gold-badge holder in the javascript tag please close this as dup. I can't since I added the javascript tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it with `JSON.parse(temp)['0_1']` as Rohit says. Note that in order to use dot notation, the identifier cannot start with a number.

[Property Accesors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

> In this code, property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

Answer (score 5):

`console.log(JSON.parse(temp)['0_1']);`

Comment: Yea Thanks for you .

Answer (score 0):

console.log(JSON.parse(temp)['0_1']);
Thanks for Rohit @Shedage @miyamoto.
I tried this method is feasible。